# Working with 2D Lists in Python: Lookup Matching and appending strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Learning python and trying to solve 2 "problems" within a small app I am building.

Essentially I have 2 lists (let's assume that in real life the lists may not be in the same order)

```
first_name_age = [["bob", 8], ["frank", 10]]
first_name_height = [["bob", "48 inches"], ["frank", "53 inches"]]
```

The first problem I am trying to solve - what would be the best way to create "first_name_height_age" where the array would be structured as:

```
first_name_height_age = [["bob", 8, "48 inches"], ["frank", 10, "53 inches"]]
```

The second question I have is - how would I append "Years old." to the 8 and 10 above? So that my new array would look like:

```
final = [["bob", "8 years old", "48 inches"], ["frank", "10 years old", "53 inches"]]
```

Comment: Does the order of the elements matter?

Comment: nope, as long as bob ends up being 48 inches at 8 years old, and frank is 10 years old at 53 inches tall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first_name_age = [["bob", 8], ["frank", 10]]
first_name_height = [["bob", "48 inches"], ["frank", "53 inches"]]

# First Part
first_name_height_age = []
for name1, age in first_name_age:
    for name2, height in first_name_height:
        if name1 == name2:
            first_name_height_age.append([name1, age, height])

print(first_name_height_age)

# Second part
for item in first_name_height_age:
    if item[1] >= 8:
        item[1] = f'{item[1]} years old'

print(first_name_height_age)
```

output :

```
[['bob', 8, '48 inches'], ['frank', 10, '53 inches']]
[['bob', '8 years old', '48 inches'], ['frank', '10 years old', '53 inches']]
```

If you enjoy one-liner list comprehensions, you can rewrite the first part like :

```
first_name_height_age = [[name1, age, height] for name1, age in first_name_age for name2, height in first_name_height if name1 == name2]
```

Answer (score 0):

use zip function

```
zipped = zip(first_name_age, first_name_height)
final= = [[name_and_age[0], age_and_height[0], age_and_height[1]] for name_and_age,age_and_height in zipped]
```

its not the best answer but easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

This will also preserve the order of the elements if that doesn't matter you could replace `list(dict.fromkeys(a + b))` with `list(set([*a, *b]))`

```
name_age = [["bob", 8], ["frank", 10]]
name_height = [["bob", "48 inches"], ["frank", "53 inches"]]

name_height_age = [list(dict.fromkeys(a + b)) for a, b in zip(name_age, name_height)]
```

You could use nested list comprehension but I find this more readable for the second problem

```
final = []
for i, sublist in enumerate(name_height_age):
    final.append([f"{i} years old" if type(i) == int else i for i in sublist])
```